# Importing Cocoapod which specifies "use_frameworks"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I have two Objective-C projects that are Cocoapods. We'll call them A and B.

A's podfile specifies "use_frameworks!". I am able to include framework header files from the pods it pulls in and build the project. A is also a pod itself (it has a .podspec)

B's podfile pulls in the A pod. B's podfile also specifies "use_frameworks!". 
When I build B, none of the A files can find their imported header files.

I'm specifying use_frameworks because I'm pulling in pods with Swift code.

Comment: I have the same problem. Seems to be ongoing at Cocoapods: https://github.com/CocoaPods/guides.cocoapods.org/issues/53